# Cursor doesn't find columns?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to load a list of values from a table, but the cursor doesn't find the columns?
The Code which is buggy:

```
public final AccessToken[] fetchAccessTokenByServerId(final long serverId) {
    final Cursor c = db.query(
            ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE,
            new String[] { ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_VALUE },
            ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_SERVER_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { Long.toString(serverId) },
            null,
            null,
            null);

    AccessToken[] result = new AccessToken[c.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_ID));
        String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_VALUE));

        result[i] = new AccessToken(value, id, serverId);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    return result;
}

public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_TABLE = "accesstoken";
public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_ID = COL_ID;
public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_SERVER_ID = "server_id";
public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_VALUE = "value";
```

But the first two statements in the for-loop fails:

> Index -1 is requested, with a size of
>   1

The table exists with the columns: _id (= int), server_id (= int) and value (= string)

There is one entry: 1, 1, test

The parameter of the function is 1.

Sincerely
xZise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after initializing your cursor, do this:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

In this part of the code I recommend it this way

*Original:*

```
AccessToken[] result = new AccessToken[c.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_ID));
    String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_VALUE));

    result[i] = new AccessToken(value, id, serverId);
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

**Modified:**

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){
   int rowCount = c.getCount();
   AccessToken[] result = new AccessToken(rowCount);
   int recCount = 0;
   while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_ID));
        String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ACCESS_TOKEN_COL_VALUE));

        result[recCount++] = new AccessToken(value, id, serverId);
        c.moveToNext();
   }
   c.close(); // <-- IMPORTANT!!!!
}
```